# PDO Get one column from a select query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get a column from a select query but i keep getting this error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

SQL

```
$row = $conn->query("SELECT * from user where name='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row->execute();
$results = $row->fetchAll();
$count = $row->rowCount();

$get_user_role = $row["name"];
echo $get_user_role;
```

Comment: Don't you need to get the value from the result set and not the statement - `$results[0]["name"]` (`[0]` as `fetch_all()` returns an array of all of the results)

Comment: I hope `$password` is not plain text, and you should reallly parameterize that query. Also if only 1 row is expected just use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to get one row from that SQL query, and by looking at your code, you do `fetchAll` which will return either `false` or an array of results with a pointer which then must be used in a loop, ie `while`.

I would do this a little bit differently (**and I introduce you to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**):

```
$row = $conn->query("SELECT * from user where name = :name and password = :password;");
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row->execute([
    'name' => $username,
    'password' => $password
]);
$result = $row->fetch();

if($result !== false) {
    $count = $row->rowCount(); 

    $get_user_role = $result["name"];
    echo $get_user_role;
} else {
    echo 'User not found or does not exist.';
}
```